# how to overcome the readonly filesystem error for a secret that is mounted in mysql image

Tags: mysql, kubernetes, kind

I'm working on setting up a mysql instance in K8s cluster with TLS support for the client connection.
For that I have setup a `cert-manager` to issue the self-signed cert. I can see `ca.crt, tls.key, tls.crt` created in the secrets within my mysql namespace successfully. I followed the following article https://www.jetstack.io/blog/securing-mysql-with-cert-manager/

Now to use this cert, my plan is to place the cert in the /var/lib/mysql directory and update the mysql.conf file using config map. Here is how the mysql.yaml pod spec looks.

```
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: mysql
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3306
  selector:
    app: mysql
  clusterIP: None
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-config
data:
  mysql.cnf: |- 
    [mysqld]
    ssl-ca=/var/lib/mysql/ca.crt
    ssl-cert= /var/lib/mysql/tls.crt
    ssl-key=/var/lib/mysql/tls.key
    require_secure_transport=ON 

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mysql
  labels:
    name: mysql
spec:
#  securityContext:
#    runAsUser: 0
  containers:
      - image: mysql:5.7
        name: mysql
        resources: {}
        env:
          # Use secret in real usage
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          value: password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: mysql
        volumeMounts:
        - name: mysql-cert-secret
          #mountPath: /app/ca.crt
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql/ca.crt
          subPath: ca.crt
        - name: mysql-cert-secret
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql/tls.crt
          #mountPath: /app/tls.crt
          subPath: tls.crt
        - name: mysql-cert-secret
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql/tls.key
          #mountPath: /app/tls.key
          subPath: tls.key
        - name: config-map-mysqlconf
          mountPath: /etc/mysql/mysql.conf
  volumes:
   - name: mysql-cert-secret
     secret:
      secretName: mysql-server-tls
   - name : config-map-mysqlconf
     configMap:
       name: mysql-config
```

If I update the mount path with say /app/ca.crt, then mounting works and I can see the certs in when I access in shell. But for the /var/lib/mysql* I get following error.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OIee.png)

I tried using the `securityContext` but it didn't help since the directory is accessible by both root and mysql user. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If there is a better way to get this done, I'm happy to try that as well.

This is all done locally using KinD cluster.

Thank you

Comment: Could you please share the error as text instead of an image because if the image is deleted, the question's quality decreases?

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/r/cyprien/mysql-tls you can use this link to setup

Comment: either you can use different mount for certificates like below 
      volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./database
              target: /var/lib/mysql
            - type: bind
              source: ./certs
              target: /etc/certs/

Answer (score 0):

MySQL stores DB files in `/var/lib/mysql` by default and there would certainly be an attempt to set the ownership to `mysql` user. Perhaps [here](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/blob/dd8e5db3bc7c717542eb867b6addde7ccc9003e2/5.7/Dockerfile.debian#L88).

Any attempt to update a secret volume will result in an error rather than a successful change as they are read-only projections into the Pod's filesystem. I think that's the reason the article you followed does not suggest anywhere to use dir `/var/lib/mysql`.

If you still want to attempt this, you can perhaps try by changing the default db storage location to something other than `/var/lib/mysql` in file `/etc/my.cnf` or even the default mode of that `volumeMount`. But I'm not sure if it will work or there won't be any other issues.

Comment: @Smukk9, can you confirm if this is resolved for you now? Keeping it open helps really no one. If you've been able to figure out some other solution, please share that instead.